# Internet Explorer Settings Through Registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to make a VBScript that automates the process of setting up new user accounts since $InsertMajorCorporationHere does not want to deploy Group Policies to do it. I have been able to do most of it through registry edits, however I can't find the registry keys for certain options in IE:

- Enable the Menu Bar
- Enable the Favorites Bar
- Enable the 'Go to Intranet site for a single word entry in the Address bar'

I have found online already an option to permanently enable the toolbars however, I would like to leave the user with the option to turn the toolbars off if they want to.

Is there a registry key for this or does anyone know a way to script it to turn the options on?

Answer (score -1):

You could save the following content to a *SetIESettings.reg* file in a folder accessible to all users and add a shortcut to *regedit /s c:\path\to\SetIESettings.reg* in the Start Up menu. Modify to suit your requirement.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MINIE]
"LinksBandEnabled"=dword:00000001
"AlwaysShowMenus"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"GotoIntranetSiteForSingleWordEntry"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: -1 give a link to the source

Comment: source: experience as windows admin

Comment: That is not a source. A source is a link you used. I really don't think you memorized those registry values so the source wasn't your head was it.

Comment: It's a direct copy paste from a link I had already found. Applying this setting for ''AlwaysShowMenus'' option does not allow users to turn the setting off in the future. I want them to be able to do that.

Comment: you dont have to remember or even have a link to find where the registry changes happen. use procmon or regshot to capture registry changes when you select those options and once you find out where the changes happen, export the relevant registry nodes, remove whatever is not relevant to the changes you need

Comment: That is awesome! I was telling myself how great it would be to have a tool that could detect that...